# Load YouTube GData feed for a single video by id

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to play a youtube video in a UIWebView instead of leaving my application.

Google thinks is easy peasy- http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

So I have the GData framework and headers working nicely, and I have no problem doing queries, loading user's video feeds etc.

But what I can't seem to do is load a specific video's feed. **I know the ids of the videos that I want the feeds for in advance**. How do i load a specific video's feed?

I'm then going to follow google's instruction :

```
Grab the video url from the media tag in the API response with the application/x-shockwave-flash type.
```

and then embed it like so:

```
// webView is a UIWebView, either initialized programmatically or loaded as part of a xib.

NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head>
<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head>
<body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">
<div><object width=\"212\" height=\"172\">
<param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"></param>
<param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param>
<embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"
type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"212\" height=\"172\"></embed>
</object></div></body></html>";

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.your-url.com"]];
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Given a feed of YouTube video entries, you can get the IDs and Flash URLs from each entry this way:

```
for (GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *videoEntry in [feed entries]) {
  GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [videoEntry mediaGroup];
  NSString *videoID = [mediaGroup videoID];

  NSArray *mediaContents = [mediaGroup mediaContents];
  GDataMediaContent *flashContent =
    [GDataUtilities firstObjectFromArray:mediaContents
                               withValue:@"application/x-shockwave-flash"
                              forKeyPath:@"type"];

  NSLog(@"video ID = %@, flash content URL = %@",
        videoID, [flashContent URLString]);   
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but how do I get that feed in the first place? I am not looking for all a user's videos, or a playlist's videos, or uploads or anything... i am looking for the feed for one particular video.

Comment: @grobbins Not sure what I am missing but I get -[GDataEntryBase mediaGroup]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Used the exact code you provided and videoEntry shows in the debugger as still being of the type GDataEntryBase (even with the GDataEntryYouTubeVideo above). Crash happens on second line trying to call mediaGroup. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In exactly the same situation just found the answer. Typically of many large APIs, common usage instructions get lost in explanation of the higher level stuff - can be frustrating. Thankfully, the info is there...

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries.html

So, we should be able to plug the returned ATOM feed into the GData library and have it parse out the proper content URL for use in the 'UIWebView' style player code.

...Grobbins, read the question properly next time!