# How to get a GDATA for a Single Youtube video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

How can I get single video information using gdata from youtube.
I know I can get a playlist using this code:
However the code does not work to get a single video's data

```
NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL85E8F3CC22BCEDC6?v=2&alt=jsonc"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];


NSDictionary *data1 = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];

NSDictionary *item = [data1 objectForKey:@"items"];

for (NSDictionary *video in item) {
    NSDictionary *title = [video objectForKey:@"video"];
    NSArray *titleArray = [title objectForKey:@"title"];

    NSLog(@"%@",titleArray);

    NSString*t  = [title objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSLog(@"Title:%@", t);

    ...
}
```

But I do not know how to get a single video.
Any help will be appreciated...
Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load YouTube GData feed for a single video by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112414/load-youtube-gdata-feed-for-a-single-video-by-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the feed for a single video with v2, you'd replace the URL in the first line with something like this:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/tge2BfiIXiE?v=2&alt=jsonc
```

Where you change the videoID as necessary.

The JSON that is returned with this feed is slightly different, naturally; so rather than creating an NSDictionary object for the items list and then looping over it, you would just do something like this:

```
NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/tge2BfiIXiE?v=2&alt=jsonc"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:feedURL];

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

NSDictionary *data1 = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];    
NSString *t  = [data1 objectForKey:@"title"];
NSLog(@"Title:%@", t);

NSDictionary *thumbs = [data1 objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]; 

NSURL *standardThumb  = [thumbs objectForKey:@"sqDefault"];
NSURL *hdThumb  = [thumbs objectForKey:@"hqDefault"];
```

**code edited to reflect question in comment**

Comment: Thanks... Your code worked great. Do you know how to then get a thumbnail from that

Comment: Luckily, the thumbnail path is also in the feed; I've updated the code above to demonstrate how to access it. As I'm not an iOS programmer I don't know how you actually retrieve the image, but that should be trivial once you have the path with the added code.

Comment: I have tried using this code but i cannot seem to get it working in the sense it is not populating my UIImageView:                           `NSURL *standardThumb  = [thumbs objectForKey:@"sqDefault"];
            NSURL *hdThumb  = [thumbs objectForKey:@"hqDefault"];
            UIImage *thumbnail =[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:hdThumb]];             [currentItem1 setImage:thumbnail]; `

Comment: If you log it -- NSLog(@"HD Thumbnail:%@", hdThumb); -- does it show a valid URL?

Comment: I loged it and it is retiring a `null value`. This is what appeared in my output: `2013-10-05 10:15:51.839 MiTube[304:19d03] HD Thumbnail:(null)`

Comment: to fix you needed:                                          `NSDictionary *thumbs = [[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];`

Comment: Good catch; again, that's why I'm not an iOS programmer! You could also do NSDictionary *thumbs = [data1 objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]; which is likely what I intended but couldn't catch. I've fixed in the code above, now (rendering all these comments moot, I guess ...)